# Angular with CanvasJS chart launched in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, canvasjs

I have CanvasJS script to plot some chart and this script is launched in `ngAfterViewInit`, for this script I got data based on which chart will be plotted in this.timeChartData which I load from `obervable`. The issue is that the script is not fully loaded in this `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle, basically the chart is empty.

```
    ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.apiService.getTimeChart().subscribe( logsFromApi => {
      this.timeChartData = logsFromApi;
    });

    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      zoomEnabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
      exportEnabled: true,

      title: {
        text: "Distribution of all events over time"
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        dataPoints: this.timeChartData
      }]
    });

      chart.render();
  }
```

the corresponding service call

```
timeChartUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/time_chart';

  getTimeChart(): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.timeChartUrl)
    return this.http.get<any>(this.timeChartUrl);
  }
```

The chart works and plots data if I attach a button to call the chart like this:

```
HTML

<button (click)="timeChart()" >butt</button>


Type script
  timeChart(){  
    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      zoomEnabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
      exportEnabled: true,

      title: {
        text: "Distribution of all events over time"
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        dataPoints: this.timeChartData
      }]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
```

I also tried to implement script launch in `ngAfterViewChecked` but this slows down application. Putting `this.apiService.getTimeChart().subscribe` into the `ngOnInit` doesn't help as well, and also I tried to put them both in `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngOnInit`. In the offical canvas.js example they just put this chart script to `ngOninit` and it works if they define static data, however in my case I am getting it from `obervable` which I think is a difference. Is there any way to fix it without clicking to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you creating chart if you put that in `ngAfterViewInit()` inside the `subscribe` block it will plot the chart. Like shown below:

```
    ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.apiService.getTimeChart().subscribe( logsFromApi => {
      this.timeChartData = logsFromApi;

    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      zoomEnabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
      exportEnabled: true,

      title: {
        text: "Distribution of all events over time"
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        dataPoints: this.timeChartData
      }]
    });

      chart.render();
  }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the chart rendering code **inside** the `subscribe` block.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.apiService.getTimeChart().subscribe( logsFromApi => {

    this.timeChartData = logsFromApi;

    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,

        title: {
        text: "Distribution of all events over time"
    },
    data: [
    {
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        dataPoints: this.timeChartData
    }]
    });

    chart.render();

  });
```

}